# Nullpointer exception when Updating a single MYSQL table record using Playframework and bean

Tags: mysql, playframework, ebean

I am new to playframework. I have updated the record using createSQLUpdate statement. I want to achieve the same using Ebean inbuilt save method.

When i execute that getting [NullPointerException: null] in   bar1.setplace in the below code.

```
public static Result updateBarbean() {
            Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
            Bar bar1 = Ebean.find(Bar.class,bar.name);
            bar1.setPlace(bar.place);
            Ebean.save(bar);
            return ok(bar.name);
            }
```

Index.scala.html

```
<h2><font color= "red">  Using bean update a record </font></h1>

<form action="@routes.Application.updateBarbean()" method="POST">
    <label for="name"> Enter Your name</label>  <input  name="name"/> <br>
    <label for="place"> Enter Your place</label>  <input name="place"/> <br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You probably don't have a record in your database that matches your `bar.name` form value. Hence `Ebean.find(Bar.class,bar.name)` returning `null` and you getting your NPE.

Comment: nope i have the value

Comment: Assuming then that you have data in your `Bar` database table, does the value from `bar.name` match the Id of your entity? I.e. is `bar.name` your entity's identifier (and not a auto generated Long value or something)? The second argument to `Ebean.find` takes the Id value of your entity. See [here](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Ebean.html#find)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to debug the play Application and look why bar.place throws a NPE. But here some possibilites that can be helpful too.

First possibility: Try using a getter:

```
bar1.setPlace(bar.getPlace());
```

In Bar.java you need the getter too.

```
public whatEver getPlace() {
    return place;
}
```

Second possibility: You say you want to update a row, right? So I think your code should look like this:

```
public static Result updateBarbean() {
        Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        Bar bar1 = Ebean.find(Bar.class,bar.name);
        bar1.setPlace(bar.place);
        Ebean.update(bar1);
        return ok(bar.name);
        }
```

Your code can be correct but I think what you want is to update the Bar object with the identifier "name". So you get `bar` from the form and `bar1` from your table. So you set the new place to bar1 and want to update it. It is important to know, that you only can update a row, if you use `update()`, because you can only use `save()` if you want to write a new one. Let me know if I misunderstood anything ;)